# How to access WSL files from an Ubuntu Dual Boot?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, dualboot

I have a dual boot set up with two separate hard drives: one for Windows and one for Linux. I also use WSL for light development work. I want to know if it is possible for me to access the WSL files from the Linux hard drive. Ordinarily, I could mount the C drive to navigate the Windows file system, but I don't know how to also (?) mount the WSL image.

Comment: Without more information, this is a bad idea.  ***PERHAPS if it were mounted READ ONLY***.  WSL controls metadata for files virtualized under root and not mnt.  Editing them WILL result in corruption.  @michal.fied (below) gives you the path.. but don't EDIT anything in it.

Comment: is it wsl 1 or 2?

Comment: @SenorCMasMas I actually corrupted the file when trying to mount it with `guestmount` in read only, so I think you are correct.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey wsl 2

Comment: Try `\\wsl$` but beware as has been said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find WSL file in this path:
C:\Users\YourAccount\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs so maybe if you mount this path then you should have access to the WSL files.

Comment: Not for me; I have a Debian 10 WSL2 instance.

Comment: Did you tired find here C:\Users\YourAccount\AppData\Local\Packages ? I think it should be in this path. In my last comment I put path to the Ubuntu instance.

Comment: Isn't that just for WSL version 1?

Comment: Okay so I'm look deeper about path and found this: 1. Run the distribution 2. Press Win+R 3. Type \\wsl$ which opens File Explorer 4. Double click on the distribution folder. This should work. I checked on WSL v1 and  after running my Ubuntu it's shows me folder with Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/access-linux-filesystems-in-windows-and-wsl-2/). I think it will tell you how to do.

TL;DR

1. (PWSH) `wmic diskdrive list brief` to get disk info
2. (PWSH admin) `wsl --mount <hard device> --partition <part id>` to mount your ext4(default) FS
3. you can access it in your WSL